# property tags in persistence.xml when using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and use Hibernate as the JPA provider. I came to know that we need `META-INF/persistence.xml` configuration file.

I successfully created a simple Java program to persist data in DB using JPA.

All fine, doubts started when I looked into the `persistence.xml` file to understand it better.

## Sample below:

```
<persistence-unit name="test-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The following is the Java code for reading the configuration:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-jpa");
```

The following are the doubts:

1. How do we know that Hibernate is the JPA provider? Is it inferred by seeing the property tags in the file?
2. In config file, there are many `<property>` tags, are they pre-defined which can appear in the file (for a given JPA provider) or can we randomly add any property? who reads those `<property>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JPA` provider would provide documentation that would tell you all of that. Doesn't yours? I'd be surprised.

1. You should either have a `<provider>` element in the persistence-unit to define which provider to use, or it would use the default for the environment that you are running in (in `JavaSE` you would need to have 1 and only one `JPA` provider in the CLASSPATH, in `JavaEE` the server would have its own default).
2. They are provider-specific. Any properties that are prefixed `javax.persistence` would be `JPA` STANDARD. The first 4 of those posted have `javax.persistence` variants that you should have used instead.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the reply. In my case,  I didn't have the <provider> tag and it still works. Now, based on your reply I can make it out that even though there is no <provider> tag and in my environment I had only hibernate jars, and guess that is the reason it was working. Is this correct conclusion? What would have been the case if I would have included both openJPA and hibernate jars and not included the <provider> tag? Would it have failed?